# html-form-enhancer doesn't change the form method

Tags: forms, npm, ecmascript-6, crud

can't get this npm module to work i need help
i tried to use

```
<script src="html-form-enhancer.mjs" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Edit <%= editCamp.title %></h1>
    <form
        action="/campgrounds/<%= editCamp._id %>"
        method="PUT"
        enctype="application/json"
        id="patchForm"
    >
        <input type="text" value="<%= editCamp.title %>" />
        <input type="text" value="<%= editCamp.price %>" />
        <input type="text" value="<%= editCamp.location %>" />
        <input type="text" value="<%= editCamp.description %>" />
        <button>confirm Edit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<script type="module">
    import { enhanceForm } from './html-form-enhancer.mjs';
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                const patchForm = document.getElementById('patchForm');
                enhanceForm(patchForm);
            });
        </script>
```

keep in mind that all it changes between the 2 is the script the rest is the same